# Checking for an empty field with MySQL

Tags: php, sql, mysql, null

I've wrote a query to check for users with certain criteria, one being they have an email address.

Our site will allow a user to have or not have an email address.

```
$aUsers=$this->readToArray('
 SELECT `userID` 
 FROM `users` 
 WHERE `userID` 
 IN(SELECT `userID`
         FROM `users_indvSettings`
  WHERE `indvSettingID`=5 AND `optionID`='.$time.')
  AND `email`!=""
 ');
```

Is this the best way to check for an empty field in SQL? I've just tried "IS NOT NULL" and this still returned a users record without them having an email address.

The query above works but out of curiosity I wondered if I'm doing it the correct way.

Answer (score 285):

An empty field can be either an empty string or a `NULL`.

To handle both, use:

```
email > ''
```

which can benefit from the `range` access if you have lots of empty email record (both types) in your table.

Comment: What is the inverse of this? (For when you want only NULL or '' fields)

Comment: @Keylan: no single expression.

Comment: @SEoF: this won't match `NULL`

Comment: @Quassnoi - if " email > '' " matches both empty and null values, then the inverse is simply inverting the output of the boolean, which is " !(email > '') " as the " email > '' " bit is being evaluated first, and then the result is being inverted. Unless you are telling me the answer to the " email > '' " is either true, false or null... then yes, it won't work.

Comment: Couldn't you just use the field `WHERE email` and then if null or empty will be handled as false

Comment: @butterbrot: any value which can't be cast into a non-zero integer will be handled as false

Comment: I have same comment as Quassnoi's. I issue "select orig_id,hotline from normal_1952 where !(hotline > '')" and there's one record with null hotline but it doesn't match.I'm using MySQL 5.6

Comment: Yes! This won't match NULL.

Comment: @SEoF - *"Unless you are telling me the answer to the " email > '' " is either true, false or null... then yes, it won't work."*    Precisely - a boolean expression involving null doesn't return either true or false. (Which is how it should be in all languages, to avoid logic mistakes. One term for this is "tri-state logic".)

Answer (score 43):

Yes, what you are doing is correct.  You are checking to make sure the email field is not an empty string.  NULL means the data is missing.  An empty string `""` is a blank string with the length of 0.

You can add the null check also

```
AND (email != "" OR email IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Your expression will match the empty strings as well. `OR email IS NOT NULL` is redundant here (it is implied by the previous condition).

Comment: Interesting, this still returns records that have an empty `email` field.

Comment: The OR should be an AND here. "OR email IS NOT NULL" will match a blank email string with length of 0.

Comment: Notice pdavis comment "OR SHOULD BE AND"

Answer (score 14):

You could use

```
IFNULL(email, '') > ''
```

Comment: Great! And you dont need the TRIM. To invert, use IFNULL(email, '') = ''.

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between an empty string (email != "") and NULL.  NULL is null and an Empty string is something.

Comment: Which is why AND (email != "" OR email IS NOT NULL) is failing?

Comment: should be `AND (email != '' AND email IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: @thetaiko: `email IS NOT NULL` is redundant here. `!=` predicate will never match a `NULL` value.

Comment: what if you try:
AND (trim(email) != '')

Comment: I know I"m rather late to this discussion, but the statement will work if you reverse the order:
"AND ((email IS NOT NULL) AND (email != '')).  If evaluated in the other order, the statement evaluates as null (not TRUE) if the email address is NULL, and thus will not be either TRUE or FALSE.   So the IS NULL check has to come FIRST!

Answer (score 2):

This will work but there is still the possibility of a null record being returned. Though you may be setting the email address to a string of length zero when you insert the record, you may still want to handle the case of a NULL email address getting into the system somehow.

```
     $aUsers=$this->readToArray('
     SELECT `userID` 
     FROM `users` 
     WHERE `userID` 
     IN(SELECT `userID`
               FROM `users_indvSettings`
               WHERE `indvSettingID`=5 AND `optionID`='.$time.')
     AND `email` != "" AND `email` IS NOT NULL
     ');
```

Comment: @op's query leaves no possibility of the `NULL` record returned.

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE TRIM(COALESCE(MyCol, '')) = ''
```

Query will return rows where MyCol is null or is any length of whitespace

See [TRIM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) and [IS NULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null) for more info.

Also [Working with null](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html) values from the MySQL docs

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all records that are not NULL, and either empty or have any number of spaces, this will work:

```
LIKE '%\ '
```

Make sure that there's a space after the backslash. More info here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Comment: wondering if this also catches strings that consist only of newlines etc.

Answer (score -3):

### **check this code for the problem:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE condition";

$res = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {

    foreach($row as $key => $field) {  

        echo "<br>";

        if(empty($row[$key])){

            echo $key." : empty field :"."<br>"; 

        }else{

        echo $key." =" . $field."<br>";     

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are better ways of doing this in query without having to loop through every single row