# If condition with is null in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am using 'if condition' in my query but its not working with `ISNULL`. Its given not value as well.

my query is

```
 SELECT *,IF(posted_job_id IS NULL,0,1)  as pj FROM appliedjob 


id|posted_job_id|pj
1 |             | 1
2 |  8          | 1
3 |  5          | 1
1 |             | 1
2 |  4          | 1
```

It showing 1 for all not null value as well. Its ok with case I mean when I am using case.

Comment: It doesn't look NULL to me, it looks "empty", so try, `IF(LENGTH(posted_job_id) > 0, 1, 0)`

Comment: I'm user2727841 check my query its working now

Comment: Thanks its also not working with null and working with posted_job_id > 0 . whats the reason behind this?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327029/checking-for-an-empty-field-with-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested this query its working now.

```
SELECT posted_job_id, IF(posted_job_id > 0, posted_job_id, 0)
AS pj FROM appliedjob
```

MySQL IF() takes three expressions and if the first expression is true, not zero and not NULL, it returns the second expression. Otherwise it returns the third expression.

Suppose first experssion is `if` condition if its true, it return second experssion which is the body of `if` condition otherwise it will return third experssion which is just like `else`.

Comment: Thanks can u tell me why ISNULL not working ? while posted_job_id > 0 is working.

Comment: MySQL IS NULL operator tests whether a value is NULL. If satisfied, then returns 1 otherwise returns 0.

Comment: In condition I checked posted_job_id is greater than 0 print database values like 8, 5 and 4 but if its not greater than 0 print 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 0 in case of null and the original value in case of not null, try this

```
SELECT *, IF(posted_job_id IS NULL, 0, posted_job_id) AS pj 
FROM appliedjob
```

Answer (score 0):

you can only check posted_job_id > 0 in SQL

```
SELECT *,IF(posted_job_id > 0, 1, 0)  as pj FROM appliedjob
```