# Comparing empty strings if it is not equal to MySQL column with string values

Tags: mysql, string, coldfusion-2016

I'm not sure if this scenario is related only to Coldfusion or Mysql.

If a column that is of type TEXT is compared to an empty string value if it is not equal, this code works:

```
column > ""
```

but not this one:

```
column != ""
```

In my SQL code, let's say the database column attachment with a TEXT type has strings contained in it. The Form value of the Input Attachment (**:attachment**) is empty (I think it will refer to **""**).

```
attachment = ( 
    CASE 
        WHEN :attachment = "" AND attachment = "" 
            THEN 1 
        WHEN :attachment = "" AND attachment != "" 
            THEN 2 
        WHEN :attachment != "" AND attachment = "" 
            THEN 3
        WHEN :attachment != "" AND attachment != "" 
            THEN 4 
        ELSE attachment 
    END 
)
```

this code would return attachment = 3.

However, if I use this SQL code:

```
attachment = ( 
    CASE 
        WHEN :attachment = "" AND attachment = "" 
            THEN 1 
        WHEN :attachment = "" AND attachment > "" 
            THEN 2 
        WHEN :attachment > "" AND attachment = "" 
            THEN 3
        WHEN :attachment > "" AND attachment > "" 
            THEN 4 
        ELSE attachment 
    END 
)
```

This code returns attachment = 2 which is what I really am expecting to have.

So, what's the best way to compare a column if it is equal or if it is not equal to an empty string? I rarely use NULL values because when FORM are saved, they input empty strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking for an empty field with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327029/checking-for-an-empty-field-with-mysql)

Comment: Don't use double quotes to compare strings in the database change all of then to single quotes and test it again!

Comment: Why shouldn't I use double quotes? @JorgeCampos

Comment: @Pyromonk I'm checking if it is not equal, not if it is equal. I check the link you tagged and I didn't seem to find the exact answer to my question.

Comment: SQL ANSI standards. Double quotes is for identifiers as if you are creating a new column name. Single quotes is for string comparison.

Comment: http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~len/sql1999.pdf is big... take your time

Comment: FYI, based on the subject I assume `> ""` is just a typo for `<> ""`. If that is not correct, feel free to roll back the edit.

Comment: @KaySingian - While you can use `>` (greater than) with strings, it does not mean the same thing as `<>` (not equal to). Perhaps that was part of the original issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should use <> instead of != and also use single quotation instead of double quotation e.g.

```
WHEN :attachment <> '' AND attachment <> ''
```

Comment: Neither of these things should actually be relevant in the MySQL dialect.  Double quotes for strings are accepted unless the server has [`ANSI_QUOTES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) enabled, and if it did, these queries would throw an error.  For inequality, `!=` and `<>` are [equivalent](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal).

Answer (score 0):

Warning: NEVER use `column > ''`

I just had some cases with MySql 5.7, where `column > ''` resulted in FALSE,
but `column < ''` resulted in TRUE!!

So better check for `LENGTH(column)`